# Multiple Values in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter

I'm learning SQL and I'm trying to run a query where the results return with orders from several product numbers. However, I think I'm making a mistake when it comes to listing those product numbers in the filter of my query. I am certain that at least 2 orders have been placed of product 1201 as I have run the numbers in individual queries, but when I add additional numbers, I get zero results.

My query:

```
SELECT 
   h.customer_number, h.product_number, h.del_qty
FROM 
   customer_del_hist AS h 
INNER JOIN 
   inv_master AS i ON i.product_number = h.product_number
WHERE 
   (i.product_number = '1200, 1201, 1202, 1203')
```

Answer (score 4):

You want `in`.  If these are numbers, then you do not want single quotes either:

```
WHERE i.product_number IN (1200, 1201, 1202, 1203)
```

If, you are getting a datatype error, then the values are not numbers.  Use single quotes in that case:

```
WHERE i.product_number IN ('1200', '1201', '1202', '1203')
```

(Why a field called "product_number" would not have a number is an interesting self-referential paradox.)

Comment: I modified the query accordingly and received the following error: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '006R01179XER' to data type int.

Comment: If your i.product_number field is not actually a number (as the error suggests) you can compare the strings instead, placing the single quotes around each product_number and using the comma as a delimiter:   `WHERE i.product_number IN ('1200', '1201', '1202', '1203')`

Answer (score 1):

You Query(ie: '=" )searches for the **'1200, 1201, 1202, 1203'** string not the values present in that place you need to use in operator for multiple values or
as

```
WHERE  i.product_number  in(1200,1201,1202)
```

You can go with

```
WHERE i.product_number =1200 OR i.product_number =1201 OR i.product_number =1202 OR i.product_number =1203
```

Answer (score 1):

Your can further extend Gordon's answer by using subquery

```
where i.product_number in (select id from all_products)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `WHERE IN` clause
 `WHERE in ('1200, 1201, 1202, 1203')`